# Vector addition and multiplication, adding error

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, operator-overloading

I'm supposed to create a program that is used to multiply or and/or add vectors. I'm supposed to do this using classes and overloading the built in functions like "+" and "str". I've done most of it but my problem is when I run the cases

```
v1 = Vector([2, 3, 4])
v2 = Vector([1, 2, 2])
v2[3] = 3
print(str(v2) == 'Vector: [1, 2, 3]')
print(str(v1 + v2) == 'Vector: [3, 5, 7]')
print(str(v2 * 2) == 'Vector: [2, 4, 6]')
print(str(2 * (v1 + v2)) == 'Vector: [6, 10, 14]')
```

For the last case I receive false, I did some poking around and found that my function is storing the data from the previous cases and is using them to compute the last case.

using `print(str(v1 + v2) == 'Vector: [3, 5, 7]')
      print(str(v2 * 2) == 'Vector: [2, 4, 6]')`
as the 2 vectors instead and getting `Vector: [10, 18, 26]` as an output

my code is below:

```
class Vector:
     def __init__(self,l):
         if (isinstance(l,list) == False):
             raise TypeError
         elif(isinstance(l,list)):
             for i in l:
                 if (isinstance(i, int) == False and isinstance(i,int) == False):
                     raise TypeError
                 else:
                     self.l = l

     def dim(self):
         return len(self.l)

     def __getitem__ (self,i):
         if i > len(self.l) or i < 1:
             raise IndexError
         return (self.l[i-1])

     def __setitem__(self, i, x):
         if i > len(self.l) or i < 1:
             raise IndexError
         self.l[i-1] = x

     def __str__(self):
         print ("Vector: "+ str(self.l))
         return ("Vector: "+ str(self.l))

     def __add__(self, other):
         if (not isinstance(other, Vector)):
             raise ValueError
         elif(other.dim() != self.dim()):
             raise ValueError

         for i in range(0,len(self.l)):
             self.l[i] = self.l[i] + other[i+1]
         return Vector(self.l)

     def __mul__(self, other):
         if (isinstance(other,float)) or (isinstance(other,int)):
             for j in range (0, len(self.l)):
                 self.l[j] = self.l[j] * other 
             return Vector(self.l)
         elif (isinstance(other, Vector)):
             for i in range(0,len(self.l)):
                 self.l[b] = self.l[b] * other[i+1]
             return sum(self.l)
         else:
             raise AssertionError

     def __rmul__(self,other):

         if (isinstance(other,float)) or (isinstance(other,int)):
             for k in range (0, len(self.l)):
                 self.l[k] = self.l[k] * other
             return Vector(self.l)
         elif (isinstance(other, Vector)):
             for i in range(0,len(self.l)):
                 self.l[b] = self.l[b] * other[i+1]
             return sum(self.l)

         else:
             raise AssertionError
```

How can I fix this unwanted overwriting?

Comment: When you do v1 + v2 you are editing v1 and then returning a copy of it. You need to copy it first and then edit --- Actually you're not even making a copy but reusing the same inner list on the next vector

Comment: so then I should return a different value? but when I do this my function doesn't run through the str function after to add on the "Vector:" part of the code

Comment: In your code, copy the `l` to a temporary var for computing purposes, and preventing changing the original values. For example, in `__add__` function:  `new_l = self.l[:] \n for i in range(0,len(new_l)): new_l[i] += other[i+1] \n return Vector(new_l)`

Comment: I should probably do this to my other functions as well correct? Also sidenote, how can I put your comment as the answer to this question?

Comment: Please do not add this as an answer, this is just general debugging talk, that is not relevant to others.